# PHP Multidimensional array sort keeping one element value at first position

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array named $newArray have below values:

```
$newArray = 
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 1
            [PostID] => 1
            [id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 0.1
            [PostID] => 2
            [id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 241
            [val] => 0.3
            [PostID] => 3
            [id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 135
            [val] => 0.02
            [PostID] => 4
            [id] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 0.003
            [PostID] => 5
            [id] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 5
            [PostID] => 6
            [id] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 4
            [PostID] => 23
            [id] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 2
            [PostID] => 1
            [id] => 7
        )

    [8] => 
)
```

I want to sort `[CountryID]` in DESC, `[val]` in DESC order only after filtering one element value "24" of `[CountryID]` on top (with `[val]` DESC of course), so result should be below:

```
$newArray = 
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 24
                [val] => 2
                [PostID] => 1
                [id] => 7
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 24
                [val] => 1
                [PostID] => 1
                [id] => 0
            )       

        [3] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 24
                [val] => 0.003
                [PostID] => 5
                [id] => 4
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 355
                [val] => 5
                [PostID] => 6
                [id] => 5
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 355
                [val] => 4
                [PostID] => 23
                [id] => 6
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 355
                [val] => 0.1
                [PostID] => 2
                [id] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 241
                [val] => 0.3
                [PostID] => 3
                [id] => 2
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [CountryID] => 135
                [val] => 0.02
                [PostID] => 4
                [id] => 3
            )   

    )
```

What function I should use here in order to sort a multidimensional array with above order and condition?

I am still learning arrays in php and limited knowledge of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract value which you need later, and filter the array to avoid warning.

```
$inputSearch = 24;
$k = array_keys(array_column($newArray, 'CountryID'), 24);    
foreach($k as $v){
    $temp[] = $newArray[$v];    
    unset($newArray[$v]);
}
array_multisort(array_column($temp, 'val'), SORT_DESC, $temp);
$newArray = array_filter($newArray);
array_multisort(array_column($newArray, 'CountryID'), SORT_DESC,array_column($newArray, 'val'),      SORT_DESC,$newArray);
$newArray = array_merge($temp , $newArray);                
print_r($newArray);
```

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) - Return the values from a single column in the input array
[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - Filters elements of an array using a callback function
[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays
[array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/723499c640e93d71cdb0cc49328843ffe66df751).

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 2
            [PostID] => 1
            [id] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 1
            [PostID] => 1
            [id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 24
            [val] => 0.003
            [PostID] => 5
            [id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 5
            [PostID] => 6
            [id] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 4
            [PostID] => 23
            [id] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 355
            [val] => 0.1
            [PostID] => 2
            [id] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 241
            [val] => 0.3
            [PostID] => 3
            [id] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [CountryID] => 135
            [val] => 0.02
            [PostID] => 4
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: It works when element value is unique, can we select all those on top. . For ex in above, if I replace 135 to 24 then it should sort accordingly.

Comment: It will work, if there is only one any CountryID, do you want it for multiple countryIDs?

Comment: Yes please. It should matched values on top and then sort it inside as per ['val']. After that rest should be as per ['CountryID'] DESC and ['val'] DESC

Comment: Updated my answer as per requirement, you haven't mentioned top values sorting order as per `val`. So by default `array_multisort(array_column($temp, 'val'), SORT_ASC, $temp);` here I kept desc. Please check demo for your result output.

Comment: I was not meant for multiple values to be searched but one value in multiple instances. For example, CountryID = 24, value should be - https://justpaste.it/3eo2f

Comment: That is possible through old code, you could have replaced 135 with 24, and it will work, now also, if you give that multiple search array one value it will work,

Comment: Sorry but that is not working, it picks only first result on top not for all searches/filter having countryID 24, I have edited my question above with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using [***usort***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) you can solve your problem. Example:

```
usort($newArray, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['CountryID'] == 135 OR $b['CountryID'] == 135) return 1;
    $retval = $b['CountryID'] - $a['CountryID'];
    if ($retval == 0) {
        $retval = $b['val'] - $a['val'];
    }
    return $retval;
});

echo '<pre>', print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: It sorts all array in DESC without keeping "135" on top. Also, please have a look at my above comment!